# Play framework: Why does https url not work on using "sbt dist" command?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, sbt, playframework-2.6

I am trying to create executable file for deploying my web app using play framework sbt dist command. When I run my application using "sbt run" command then https work but when I use sbt dist and run my executable file to start my app then only http url works.

Following is my configuration

In build.sbt

```
javaOptions ++= Seq(
  "-Dhttps.keyStore=conf/keystore.jks",
  "-Dhttps.keyStorePassword=*****",
  "-Dhttp.port=9000",
  "-Dhttps.port=9001",
  "-Dsentry.dsn=https://****"
)
```

In application.conf

```
play.http {

  session {
    secure = true
    httpOnly = true
    domain = "localhost"
  }

  flash {
    secure = true
    httpOnly = true
  }
}

play.ws {
  ssl {
    trustManager = {
      stores = [
        { type = "JKS", path = "conf/keystore.jks" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess problem is `conf/keystore.jks` relative path in `application.conf`. Try just `keystore.jks` maybe... not sure.

Comment: In that case it should have thrown error like keystore.jks doesn't exist and it did when i tried with just keystore.jks.

Comment: Usually with command `sbt run` it outputs on console like `Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000` and `Listening for HTTPS on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9001` but in this case it just output for HTTP and doesn't give any info about HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `javaOptions` in `Universal`:

```java
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
  "-Dhttps.keyStore=conf/keystore.jks",
  "-Dhttps.keyStorePassword=*****",
  "-Dhttp.port=9000",
  "-Dhttps.port=9001",
  "-Dsentry.dsn=https://****"
)
```

See https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html#via-build-sbt

However, why not just define those settings in `conf/application.conf`?

Comment: Well this small change solved my problem. Thanks a lot @mkurz! you are a life saver.

Comment: Since you suggested that these settings should be in `conf/application.conf` so I want to know if it is advantageous. As I am beginner in `scala/play framework` so I don't have that depth understanding. Thanks!