# Docker: Play framework application exits with code 0

Tags: java, scala, docker, playframework, docker-compose

I am working on dockerizing my scala play framework application. Docker builds successfully but docker run exits with code 0.

```
user-service | [info] Loading project definition from /app/project
user-service | [info] Set current project to user-service (in build file:/app/)
user-service | 
user-service | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
user-service | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app/lib/logback-classic-1.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
user-service | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
user-service | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop/jars/slf4j-nop-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
user-service | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
user-service | SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
user-service | --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
user-service | 
user-service | [info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9004
user-service | 
user-service | (Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)
user-service | 
user-service | [info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Stopping server...
user-service | 
user-service | [success] Total time: 4 s, completed Apr 2, 2020 10:40:20 AM
user-service exited with code 0
```

### My Dockerfile

```
FROM sshek2019/docker-scala

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY

EXPOSE 9004

CMD ["sbt", "run"]
```

### My docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  api:
    build: .
    container_name: user-service
    expose:
      - "9004"
    ports:
      - "9004:9004"
```

Comment: Can you run docker in debug mode,

Comment: How to run docker in debug mode?

Comment: One more thing I want to tell that it runs fine in case of interactive terminal mode.

Comment: Play's setup [includes the sbt-native-packager plugin](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Deploying#The-Native-Packager), which includes [support to build a Docker image](https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats/docker.html).  You might try configuring that in your `build.sbt` file and then using `sbt docker:publishLocal` to get an image out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config says that on enter/closed std-in you app should be closed, which terminates it right after turning it on. You should disable [development mode](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/PlayConsole) for docker image.

For instance you can use [test instance mode](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Deploying#Running-a-test-instance):

```
CMD ["sbt", "runProd"]
```

However, you should rather run sbt in Docker in interactive mode so that std-in won't be immediately closed.

```
docker run --it ...
```

Comment: But how to run it in interactive mode using docker-compose file?

Comment: Either you run a particular service `docker-compose run [flags] service` which should run it in interactive mode, or (if you use docker up) you not require any of your services to need it - with sbt it's `runProd` but usually for `docker-compose up` you shouldn't use sbt but prebuild image

Comment: There is one more way to solve this problem which is by using `sbt dist` command and use the generated executable file in docker but then another issue comes in picture i.e. in this case only `http` url works and `https` doesn't. I have already created a separate stackoverflow post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60887982/play-framework-why-does-https-url-not-work-on-using-sbt-dist-command?noredirect=1#comment107727848_60887982]